# Retrieving information from Rails 4 associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

What is the most efficient way for retrieving all unique venues with a specified set of features?

In the controller, I have:

```
@venues = Venue.all
@venues = @venues.features.where('feature.id == ' 1).distinct
```

Here's how my models are defined:

```
class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
  has_many :features
end

class FeatureType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :features  
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :feature_type
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think about this using English.  If a Venue has many Features and you ask "What is the Id of the Feature?" the response is going to be: "There are many Features, which one?"

The `:has_many` association gives you the following method: `venure.features`.  That gives you all the of the "many" associated features.  To get the Id of just one, you could do something like: `venue.features.first.id`.

Comment: Good point, Messick; however, I did actually have the code in a loop (see edited question for additional code).  For some reason, rails isn't picking up the "id" field.  Thoughts?

Comment: I've edited the question to put back in your original text so our answers make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Venue `has_many` features, so you must loop over the collection, vs a `belongs_to` where there is a single relationship between the models

```
<% venue.features.each do |feature| %>
  <%= debug feature %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the debug method, house9.  I actually did have a loop around the code (see edited question).  Regardless, the error that I'm getting is that rails doesn't recognize the "id" field.  Thoughts?

Comment: When you write sql fragments you need to pluralize the table names - features.id